# Determine when the process $\exp(\lambda t + \sigma W(t))$ is a sub- or a supermartingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $\{ W(t) \}_{t\in \mathbb [0,\infty)}$ be a Wiener-Process and define 
$$ 
 X(t) := e^{\lambda t + \sigma W(t)}
$$
for $\lambda, \sigma \in \mathbb R$. I want to know under what conditions on $\lambda$ and $\sigma$, the above process is a sub- or a supermartingale for the canonical filtration $\mathfrak F^W$ on $W(t)$?

Using the [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) I find that $E[X] = \exp\left( \lambda t + \frac{\sigma^2 t}{2} \right)$. But I do not know how to compute the conditional expectation $E[X(t) \mid \mathfrak F^W(s)]$ in general for $s \le t$?

I know that $E[W(t) \mid \mathfrak F^W(s)] = E[W(t) - W(s) + W(s) \mid \mathfrak F^W(s)] = (t-s) + W(s)$ by independence. If $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is convex, we have $f(E[W(t) \mid \mathfrak F^W(s)]) \le E(f(W(t)) \mid \mathfrak F^W(s))$ which gives by the above $e^{\lambda t + \sigma((t-s) + W(s))} \le E(e^{\lambda t + \sigma W(t)} \mid \mathfrak F(s))$, i.e.
$$
 e^{(\lambda + \sigma)(t - s)} e^{\lambda s + \sigma W(s)} \le E(e^{\lambda t + \sigma W(t)} \mid \mathfrak F(s))
$$
hence if $(e^{(\lambda + \sigma)})^{t-s} \ge 1$ this is a submartingale, which is fulfilled if $\lambda + \sigma \ge 0$. So a partial result is that if $\lambda + \sigma \ge 0$, the process is a submartingale. But I do not know what happens if $\lambda + \sigma < 0$, and when the process is a supermartingale?

Comment: You've almost answered the question yourself. Note that $$E[X(t)\mid \mathcal F_s] = \exp\{\lambda t + \sigma W(s)\} E[\exp\{ \sigma (W(t) - W(s))\}\mid \mathcal F_s] \\= \exp\{\lambda t + \sigma W(s)\} E[\exp\{ \sigma (W(t) - W(s))\}]$$
thanks to the independence of increments.

Comment: @zhoraster I totally overlooked that. Using it I found that it is a submartingale for $\lambda \ge 0$ and never a supermartingale, would be glad if you would take a look at my solution.

Comment: Your computation of $E[ \exp(\sigma(W(t) - W(s)) ]$ is incorrect (already homogeneity reasons should have alerted you, since $W(t)-W(s)$ is $\sqrt{t-s}$ times a standard normal random variable, not $t-s$ times a standard normal random variable).

Comment: @Did Thanks for your feedback. I started everything from scratch, hope now everything works out well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the hint of @zhoraster, we have
\begin{align*}
 E[X(t) \mid \mathfrak F(s)] & = \exp(\lambda t + \sigma W(s)) E[\exp(\sigma(W(t) - W(s)) \mid \mathfrak F(s) ] \\
     & = \exp(\lambda t + \sigma W(s)) E[\exp(\sigma(W(t) - W(s))]                       
\end{align*}
by independence. In the following we use the fact that if $X \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$, then
$$
 E[e^{\sigma X}] = e^{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}.
$$
As by the law of the unconscious statistician (and completing the square) we have
\begin{align*}
 E[e^{\sigma X}] & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\sigma z} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2} ~ d z \\
 & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\sigma z - z^2/2} ~ d z \\
 & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(z - \sigma\right)^2 - \sigma^2\right)} ~ dz \\
 & = e^{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(z - \sigma\right)^2} ~ d z \\
 & = e^{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}.
\end{align*}
Using this we find
$$
 E[e^{\sigma(W(t) - W(s))}]
  = E\left[e^{\sigma \sqrt{t - s} \frac{W(t) - W(s)}{\sqrt{t-s}}}\right]
  = e^{\frac{\sigma^2(t-s)}{2}}.
$$
Hence
\begin{align*}
 E[X(t) \mid \mathfrak F(s)] 
 & = e^{\lambda t + \sigma W(s)} e^{\frac{\sigma^2(t-s)}{2}} \\
 & = e^{\lambda s + \sigma W(s)} e^{\lambda(t-s) e^{\frac{\sigma^2(t-s)}{2}}} \\
 & = e^{\lambda s + \sigma W(s)} e^{(t-s)(\lambda + \sigma^2/2)}
\end{align*}
And so we have a supermartingale if $\lambda + \sigma^2/2 \le 0$, and a submartingale if $\lambda + \sigma^2/2 \ge 0$.